# Reload HTML elements with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get a list of items and use it to dynamically create an HTML list

```
_loadList(){
    HttpUtils.get('http://myserver/list/users/')
    .then((res) => {
        const self = this;
        res.forEach((item) => {
            userListContainer.append('<li> item.name </li>')
        });
    });
}
```

I call this function in the constructor, everything is working fine

```
constructor() {
    this._loadList();
}
```

I am trying to recall this function every 5 seconds to update the list with the new result:

```
constructor() {
    const that = this;
    this._loadList();
    window.setInterval(function(){
        that._loadList();
    }, 5000);
}
```

The function is called, the received result contains the new content, but the HTML is not updated. Do you have an idea about the problem?

Comment: You're missing more than a couple `'` or `"`s.

Comment: You don't empty the container before appending?

Comment: @pete how can I do that?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code that will work for in your case. You can checkout `https://es6console.com/jgyxgm1f/` example which will alert random number (in your case it's equivalent of adding new data coming from API response).

```
_loadList = () => {
   HttpUtils.get('http://myserver/list/users/')
     .then((res) => {
       userListContainer.empty();
       res.forEach((item) => {
          userListContainer.append('<li> item.name </li>')
       });
   });
 }

constructor = () => {
    this._loadList();
    window.setInterval(() => {
        this._loadList();
    }, 5000);
}
```